# How to set response for different camel endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a servlet route

```
from("servlet:/?matchOnUriPrefix=true").to("cxfbean:jaxrsServicesproviders=jaxrsProviders")
```

And i am using the below code to set the response.

```
if (fromEndpoint.equals(SERVLET_ENDPOINT)) {
        String jsonInString = getJSonString(error);
        exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonInString, HttpServletResponse.class);
        if (Status.fromStatusCode(error.getResponseCode()) == null) {
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Status.FORBIDDEN.getStatusCode());
        } else {
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, error.getResponseCode());
        }
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    }
```

And when there is a RESTLET route

`from("restlet:/matchOnUriPrefix=true").to("cxfbean:jaxrsServicesproviders=jaxrsProviders")`

I am using this code.

```
if (fromEndpoint.equals(RESTLET_ENDPOINT)) {
        org.restlet.Response response = ((org.restlet.Response) exchange.getIn().getHeader(RestletConstants.RESTLET_RESPONSE, org.restlet.Response.class));
        org.restlet.data.Status status = org.restlet.data.Status.valueOf(error.getResponseCode());
        if (status == null) {
            response.setStatus(org.restlet.data.Status.CLIENT_ERROR_FORBIDDEN);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(status);
        }
        String jsonInString = getJSonString(error);
        response.setEntity(jsonInString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        exchange.getOut().setBody(response);
```

Now if i try to use a different endpoint like spring-ws

`from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://camel.apache.org/example/increment}incrementRequest?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
                .unmarshal(jaxb)
                .process(new IncrementProcessor())
                .marshal(jaxb);`

How do i set response.?Is there a generic way for setting response for all the endpoints instead of checking for each endpoint type.?

Comment: How do you think about creating a common Processor for all the endpoints?

Comment: Even if i create a common processor i still need to check for different endpoints to set the response as i am setting the response to org.restlet.Response for restlet and HttpServletResponse for Servlet endpoint